# What should i use to create custom ListView in Fragment to suit my need?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I've been creating News application. I used [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) to create good-looking Navigation Drawer. It uses fragments for every category in Navigation List. I will be using provided API to get news (in the JSON format), and i need customized List View to show the list of news. When you click list item, it will open new view to show details of news. I've found several tutorials, but none of them worked for fragment. Please, tell me way to do it.

[image: My Layouts]
[image: My Fragments]

I'm new to Android Programming. This is my first project, though it is too hard for being first project. But i have to do it. Please, help!

**Thanks beforehand!**

Comment: Your turorial is working with fragments. So what is your question?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi, i would like to have another tutorial to build customized list view (with image, icon, several text areas). Most of customized list view tutorials work with activity. Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I would suggest to switch to RecyclerView, which is where Google is pushing the developper to, it also natively integrates the ViewHolder concept. You got great guided example here : https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: @PlumillonForge, thank you so much! I will give it a try. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to create an adapter and a custom row layout from a tutorial that works for activities. Minor modifications will help you using fragments.

Your fragment should look like this:

```
public class NewFragment extends Fragment{

    CustomAdapter listAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Data> yourData; // Should be filled with data from your JSONParser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        /*
        * Use your custom adapter. in this example the adapter need 
        * the context and an array that contains your data
        */
        listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),yourData);  

        ...

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);

        listView = (LsitView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_list);

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        ...


    }

}
```

Comment: @JawadLeWyadi, thank you so much! I will try that today and if it works i will accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this `ListFragment`:

Here is a fully customized example:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

mylist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

myitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/txt_mytext" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment fr = mListFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, fr, "tag").commit();
    }
}
```

mListFragment.java

```
public class mListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static mListFragment newInstance() {
        mListFragment f = new mListFragment();
        //Bundle args = new Bundle();

        //f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
    public mListFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new LstAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.myitem,
                strings);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
    }

    public class LstAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private String[] mArray;

        public LstAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] mList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, mList);
            mArray = mList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mArray.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mArray[position];
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myitem, null);
            }

            TextView tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_mytext);
            tvName.setText(mArray[position]);

            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("123", position + "");
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
}
```